# Вывести таблицу из mysql с датами на сайте с переводом часового пояса для клиента

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

Как правильно сделать, с точки зрения производительности?

В mysql в таблице есть дата формата (2018-10-31 21:46:47)
нужно чтобы все даты в таблице при выводе клиента были конвертированы в часовой пояс этого клиента

Лучше конвертировать в mysql запросе или уже в php?

Comment: у тебя сервер на pentium-133?

Comment: Выбирайте с помощью [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-unix_timestamp-function.php), а дальше играйтесь с временными зонами по своему усмотрению.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все преобразования производим в коде. Например следующим образом:

```
$la_time = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow');

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $utc_date = new DateTime($row['date']);

    printf(
        "Date in UTC %s, Date in user timezone (Moscow): %s", 
        $utc_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        $utc_date->setTimezone($la_time)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    );
}
```

[Share & run PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=a81ee90591900b373cc604c533ddcabe&sqlses=9049b77c0422beeba49a41372bdca4f7&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)